# Why does k-means have more bias than spectral clustering and GMM?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, clustering, bias

I ran into a 2019-Entrance Exam question as follows:

> Which of the following algorithm has the higher bias?
>
> 1. GMM
> 2. GMM (identity covariance matrix)
> 3. spectral clustering
> 4. k-means

The answer mentioned is (4), but some search on google showed me maybe (1) and (2) is equal to (4). Why would k-means be the algorithm with the highest bias? (Can you please also provide references to valid material to study more?)

Comment: GMMs allow for overlapping clusters.  I believe, but am not positive, that spectral clustering can, too.  OTOH, k-means cannot have overlapping clusters.  That means the result has to be biased any time the actual clusters aren't completely separated.

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica what is your idea about that k-means is GMM under some constrains. So it has more bias.

Comment: That seems like a reasonable way to think about it.  If you want, I can try to make this a formal answer later (no time now...).

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica yes, Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Gaussian mixture models allow for overlapping clusters, and for non-spherical clusters.  I'm pretty sure (albeit not positive) that this is true of spectral clustering as well.  On the other hand, k-means cannot find overlapping clusters, and the clusters it outputs are essentially spherical.  Those facts will cause bias unless the true clusters are spherical and completely separated in reality.